# Find A value in list , if there are multiple value print all the values else print the corresponding values from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, speech-recognition

I have two lists :

```
Keyword = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'White Cat', 'Lion', 'Black Cat']
Definition = ['Mans Best Friend', 'The cat is a domestic species of a small carnivorous mammal', 'White  cats are cute', 'Lions are Carnivores Wild Animal', 'Black Cats are Black in color']
```

I am getting a voice input in 'query' from the following command:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
     
    r = sr.Recognizer()
     
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
  
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")   
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
  
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)   
        print("Unable to Recognize your voice.") 
        return "None"
     
    return query

query = takeCommand().Capitalize()
```

Now if the query contains Dog in it I want to print the corresponding definition from  the list i.e. 'Man's Best Friend', If the query contains Cat , I want to show the user that there are multiple Keywords that have 'Cat' in them i.e. 'Cat', 'White Cat', 'Black Cat' and if the word inside query isn't in the list I want to print "No keywords Found, Please check your Keyword"

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Input output for different cases:

Input: query has 'Dog' in it. The program should check for if there are more than 1 word that has Dog in it. If Yes it should print all the keywords that has Dog in it, if No then it should print the corresponding definition . In this case of Keywords the output for Dog should be the corresponding definition i.e. 'Mans Best Friend'.

Input: Query has 'Cat' in it. In this case of keywords there are 3 keywords that have cat in them i.e. 'Cat' , 'Black Cat', 'White Cat' So here the code should Print these Keywords instead of their definition. So output of this case : We have found multiple keywords : 'Cat' , 'Black Cat', 'White Cat'

Input : Query has 'Panther' in it. There is no Panther in Keywords So it should print "There are no Matching Keywords".

Comment: What if the query is "white dog"? Would you expect all results with a 'keyword' containing either "white" or "dog" or both? Or would you expect no result because there is no 'keyword' that includes all the parts of the query? The 'keyword' really is more a key phrase, it seems?

Comment: That Should be no keywords found. Yes its just an example.

Comment: This is not that hard, but you need to make some attempt to do it yourself.  Step one is to combine those two lists into a dictionary, so you can look up the body given the keyword.  You will have to enumerate through all of the keys to see if there are multiple matches.  And I would switch to lower case instead of capitalizing.

Comment: And "cat white", also no result? Or should that return "white cat" as a result?

Comment: "cat white" should result in "white cat" if possible, but not necessary if that makes the code too complex.

Comment: @TimRoberts is there a way i can capitalize first word of the list? i dont wanna use .lower( ) cuz it doesn't looks good. So suppose if user said 'White Cat' the  capitalize function only converts to 'White cat' but i wanna print 'White Cat' where both are capital.

Comment: First make it work, then make it pretty.  If you keep the keys as lower case, it will be easier to search.  You can fix the capitalization when you print it.

Comment: Most of the time when the user inputs voice data  it will be in lower case and also the program will only respond if the voice input exactly matches the expected keyword

Comment: @TimRoberts okay i will keep that in mind. Ty for your time.

Comment: You could use string similarity, this way you don't have to input the exact expected keyword

Comment: @PushpeshKumar , You can `.capitalize()` method of string,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Keyword = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'White Cat', 'Lion', 'Black Cat']
Definition = ['Mans Best Friend', 'The cat is a domestic species of a small carnivorous mammal', 'White  cats are cute', 'Lions are Carnivores Wild Animal', 'Black Cats are Black in color']

def take_cmd(cmd):
    multiple_val=[]
    if cmd in Keyword:
        for i,j in enumerate(Keyword):
            if cmd in j:
                multiple_val.append((i,j))
        if len(multiple_val)>1:
            i_removed=[j for i in multiple_val for j in i if type(j)!=int]
            print(f"We have found multiple keywords : {i_removed}")
        else:
            print(Definition[Keyword.index(cmd)])
    else:
        print("There are no Matching Keywords")
```

What this code does is:

1. Checks if the value inputed exists in the `Keyword` or not, if not then would return "There are no Matching Keywords".
2. If the value exists, then would check if there are multiple instances or the value is available in multiple indexes or not.
3. If that returns true as well then it appends it to `multiple_vals`. If length of `multiple_val` if greater than 1 then only it would show `f"We have found multiple keywords : {i_removed}"`.
4. otherwise shows the corresponding index in `Definition`.